# Expandable ListView doesn't expand/collapse on a click

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm not sure what I missed, though I followed a tutorial it seems I have a problem I couldn't track.

**Some background:**

First of all, my list doesn't have any children at the beginning. After the user creates a group, the app also adds the first child. the first child is a dummy child since it doesn't have any data in it. The `getChildView` method (in `MyListAdapter`) that inflate the view has 2 cases: a case for the first child, and a case for the rest of the children. The second case doesn't matter at the moment since I didn't define it yet. Back in the first case, I created a layout with a button, which I want to show as the first row of the list.

**The problem:**

Basically, when I add a new group it actually works, but I can't expand/collapse the header.

[image]

**The code:**
**Activity**

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinkedHashMap<Integer, WorkoutGroup> mySection = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private ArrayList<WorkoutGroup> workoutList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private MyListAdapter listAdapter;

    //two welcome messages that disappear after the insert of the first Group.
    private TextView noWorkoutsYet;
    private TextView welcomeTitle;

    //A layout that contains the table tabs of the log
    private ConstraintLayout tableTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //Hide the text in the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //get reference to the welcome TextViews
        noWorkoutsYet = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noWorkouts_tv);
        welcomeTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome_tv);

        //get reference to the table tabs layout
        tableTabs = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableTabs);

        //get reference to the ExpandableListView
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

        //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(HomeScreen.this, workoutList);

        //check if there is more then one workout in the list
        //if so, than update the layout
        if(listAdapter.getGroupCount()>0){
            setUpdatedView();
        }

        //attach the adapter to the list
        expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //expand all Groups
        expandAll();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //get the last workout position and create a new workout
                createNewWorkout(listAdapter.getGroupCount());
            }
        });

        //listener for group heading click
        //our group listener
            expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {

                Log.d("onGroupClick:", "worked");
                parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds Groups to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar Group clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNewWorkout(int mWorkoutPosition){
        //create a dialog that ask the date of the new workout from the user
        NewWorkoutGroupFragment newWorkDialog = new NewWorkoutGroupFragment();
        newWorkDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomNewDialogFragment);
        newWorkDialog.setmWorkoutPosition(mWorkoutPosition);
        newWorkDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "getDateFragment");
    }

    //method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            expandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    //method to collapse all groups
    private void collapseAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            expandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }


    //method that insert a workout to the list by last workout position and selected date
    public void buildWorkout(int mWorkoutPosition, String mDate) {

        //check the hash map if the workout group is already exists
        WorkoutGroup workoutGroup = mySection.get(mWorkoutPosition);

        //in case there is no such workout group, create a new one
        if (workoutGroup == null) {
            workoutGroup = new WorkoutGroup();
            //set new data as a group
            workoutGroup.setmWorkoutPosition(Integer.toString(mWorkoutPosition));
            workoutGroup.setmDate(mDate);
            //put the new workout group inside the hash map
            mySection.put(mWorkoutPosition, workoutGroup);
            //insert the new workout group to the list
            workoutList.add(workoutGroup);
            //update the visibility of some view items
            setUpdatedView();

            //The first child is a dummy item;
            //it has only a button that can create a new exercise
            ExerciseItem firstChild = new ExerciseItem();
            //add it as the first child
            addItemToExerciseList(mWorkoutPosition, firstChild);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_workout_already_exists, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //This method insert an exercise to a list of exercises
    public void addItemToExerciseList(int mWorkoutPosition, ExerciseItem child) {

        WorkoutGroup workoutGroup = mySection.get(mWorkoutPosition);
        ArrayList<ExerciseItem> exerciseList = workoutGroup.getExerciseList();

        exerciseList.add(child);

        //update the changes
        workoutGroup.setExerciseList(exerciseList);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        int groupPosition = workoutList.indexOf(workoutGroup);

        //collapse all groups
        collapseAll();
        //expand the group where item was just added
        expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        //set the current group to be selected so that it becomes visible
        expandableListView.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
    }

    //update the new look of the screen after adding the first workout
    private void setUpdatedView(){
        welcomeTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        noWorkoutsYet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tableTabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

**ListAdapter**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<WorkoutGroup> workoutList;
    private Context context;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WorkoutGroup> workoutList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.workoutList = workoutList;
    }

    /* Group Methods */
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        WorkoutGroup workoutGroup = (WorkoutGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.workout_heading, null);
        }

        TextView workoutPositionHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        int workoutPositionNum = Integer.valueOf(workoutGroup.getmWorkoutPosition());
        String workoutPosition = "#" + workoutPositionNum;
        workoutPositionHeader.setText(workoutPosition);

        TextView dateHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading2);
        dateHeader.setText(workoutGroup.getmDate().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return workoutList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return workoutList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    /* Child Methods */
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ExerciseItem exerciseItem = (ExerciseItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (childPosition == 0) {
                view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.button_exercise_row, null);
            } else {
                view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_row, null);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        ArrayList<ExerciseItem> exerciseList =
                workoutList.get(groupPosition).getExerciseList();
        return exerciseList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<ExerciseItem> exerciseList =
                workoutList.get(groupPosition).getExerciseList();
        return exerciseList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**WorkoutGroup**

```
public class WorkoutGroup {

private String mWorkoutPosition = "";
private String mDate = "";
private ArrayList<ExerciseItem> exerciseList = new ArrayList<ExerciseItem>();

public WorkoutGroup() {
}

public String getmWorkoutPosition() {
    return mWorkoutPosition;
}

public void setmWorkoutPosition(String mWorkoutPosition) {
    this.mWorkoutPosition = mWorkoutPosition;
}

public String getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setmDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}

public ArrayList<ExerciseItem> getExerciseList() {
    return exerciseList;
}

public void setExerciseList(ArrayList<ExerciseItem> exerciseList) {
    this.exerciseList = exerciseList;
}
}
```

Comment: Try remove `parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);` from onGroupClick. Hope that helps!

Comment: @I_A_Mok I figured out that the app doesn't even reach to OnGroupClickListener for some reason. so it's not about the listener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100 percent sure that I wouldn't think on the solution by myself.

I found out that adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the xml file of child layout would solve this one.